# My list index is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to create a image classifier with tensorflow using python. however im getting this strange error with my index being out of range. The program is suppose to grab the files read the first 3 letters are train off whether its a cat or a dog.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm

TRAIN_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\cward\\Desktop\\images\\train'
TEST_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\cward\\Desktop\\images\\test'
IMG_SIZE = 50
LR = 1e-3

MODEL_NAME = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

def label_img(img):
    word_label = img.split('.')[-2]
    if word_label == 'cat': return[1,0]
    elif word_label == 'dog': return[0,1]

def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), 
(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])
    shuffle(traning_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', traning_data)
    return training__data

def process_test_data():
    testing_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
        img_num = img.split('.')[0]
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), 
(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])
    np.save('test_data.npy',testing_data)
    return testing_data

train_data = create_train_data()
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-40719067ea74> in <module>()
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-32-88b70eb23645> in create_train_data()
      2     training_data = []
      3     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
----> 4         label = label_img(img)
      5         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
      6         img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))

<ipython-input-31-82bc72a4ed99> in label_img(img)
      1 def label_img(img):
----> 2     word_label = img.split('.')[-2]
      3     if word_label == 'cat': return[1,0]
      4     elif word_label == 'dog': return[0,1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm brand new to python so please excuse my terrible formatting!

Comment: What is the value of `img` in `label_img(img):`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that img.split('.') has length less than 2

Do you have any directories inside of TRAIN_DIR? That would trigger this error. My personal suggestion would be to first try:

```
try:
    label = label_img(img)
except IndexError:
    print(img)
    continue
```

This should print out a list of all img values that would trigger the error. It might be the case that an image file is missing an extension. Once you have determined the error, and fixed any files, you can do:

```
if len(img.split('.')) < 2:
    continue
lable = label_img(img)
```

This would then cause the code to ignore files that would trigger the error. That way your code can still work if you have any subdirectories (though images in subdirectories would still be ignored)

Comment: Wow I feel like a moron. I did have another folder called train inside of that folder. Thanks for the help!!